# Pulling from cells in cone column and want to put in a row based in matching cell

Tags: row, match, multiple-columns

I'm trying to put any document type from column B that matches the Item Index in column A all in one row.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SQez.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Would data from A2 go with B2 and A3 with B3 etc? If so use CONCATENATE